How to metallic structure export in blender to unity
I'm having issues with baking all textures in Blender using nodes; the textures are not appearing correctly in the image. How can I bake all textures, including the metallic texture, in Blender? Please guide me through the process.
I need for help in metallic structure not in pake please help for this issue

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
